# error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int how to solve

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Drs{
    public static void main(String ... arf)
    {
        Scanner fg=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello mr.welcome");
        System.out.println("Enter the celcisus");
        int er=fg.nextInt();
        Example sk=new Example();
        sk.temparature(er);
    }
}
class Example{
    public void temparature(int sk)
    {
        int fd=1.8*(int)sk+32;
        System.out.println("your temparature value is "+fd);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int fd=1.8*(int)sk+32;` is assigning a double to an `int`. You may want to cast to int

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a full toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: change int fd=1.8*(int)sk+32; into double fd=1.8*(int)sk+32;

Comment: (ernest_k fixed it for you)

Comment: @Stultuske  - The `(int)` is unnecessary ...

Comment: @StephenC just a quick copy paste :)

Comment: It's depends on your logic and your result if you want int result then you can makes it like this `int fd = (int) 1.8 * (int) sk + 32;` or `int fd = (int) (1.8 * (int) sk + 32);` note the parenthesis in the second one or even `int fd = (int) (1.8 * sk + 32);`

Comment: If you are converting body temperature then it is usually shown with one decimal digit. So you'd better change `int` to `double` when declaring `fd`

Answer (score 0):

Use Double instead of int.

```
int er=fg.nextInt();
```

Should be:

```
double er=fg.nextDouble();
```